# Levy processes, vanilla option and Fourier Transform

Tags: calculus, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, fourier-analysis, levy-processes

The context to this problem is mathematical finance, although the answer does not need specific knowledge of the area. I am trying to work out the expression for the price of a call option using Levy Processes.

Without getting into much details, I am now stuck trying to solve the following Fourier transform:

$$
\textbf{F}f^*(z) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{iyz}(e^{y+rT} - e^k)^+dy
$$

such that $(e^{y+rT} - e^k)^+ = (e^{y+rT} - e^k) \mathbb{1}_{\{e^{y+rT} > e^k\}}$, where $r$, $T$ and $k$ are constants.

I have found the solution to this problem, but I am unable to see how one can get there:

$$
\textbf{F}f^*(z) = \frac{e^{k+iz(k-rT)}}{iz(iz+1)}
$$

It might ultimately  only have to do with classical calculus. Could somebody please show me how one can get there?

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways to solve it, but here's one:

1. Change of variables: Work with asset prices $Y=\exp(y)$ and exercise prices $K=\exp(k)$ rather than log prices $y$ and log exercise prices $k$.
2. Restrict range of integration: Option prices are bounded. Hint: $(Y-K)^+$
3. Apply the expression:

$$ \int_u^\infty x^{-v} (x-u)^{w-1} dx = u^{w-v}\beta(v-w, w)$$

The solution can be found [here](https://atrium.lib.uoguelph.ca/xmlui/bitstream/handle/10214/7811/Manuge_Derek_201401_Msc.pdf?sequence=1) phrased in terms of Mellin transforms. It should contain everything you're looking for, including the relationship between Fourier and Mellin transforms.

Comment: thanks for your answer and the reference to that paper. Unfortunately, I have to focus my research on Fourier analysis methods, so Mellin transforms would not suit me in this particular case. Perhaps some additional information on the second point you mention would help.

Comment: The Mellin transform and the Fourier transform are the same under a change of variables. The solution methods are very similar. As for point 2, $(Y-K)^+=\max(0, Y-K)$ which means we can restrict the $K <= Y <= \infty$.